# Using (thebibliography) in a separate tex file

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I have manually created my references in separate file `bio.tex` using `\begin{thebibliography}{}`. When I try to cite using `\cite{}` in another tex file `introduction.tex` it gives me error while compiling because I made the reference list in a separate file. I don't want to switch to `BibTex` because my reference list is really long and it may take long time. Is there something else I can do :(

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Make sure that you show how you are including the file. You can use the `filecontents` environment in your MWE if you wish or just post a minimal version of both files.

Comment: Please provide more information, preferably in the form of an MWE (see also @cfr's comment), about your setup. For instance, how do you include the material contained in `bio.tex` in your main document? Which error message(s) do you get? Which citation style -- numeric or author-year, or maybe something else entirely -- do you want to use? Do you load any citation management packages, e.g., the `cite` package?

Comment: Why not copy everything from `\begin{thebibliography}{}` to `\end{thebibliography}` into a file called `thebibliography.tex` and then use `\input{thebibliography}` in the new document? (If that doesn't work, please provide an MWE; it is always better -- for everyone -- when a question contains one.)

Comment: The question is tagged `biblatex` but apparently that is not in use. There are many questions in the comments, but non is answered. I vote to close as unclear.